# SMTP and multiple receivers vs single receiver

Tags: smtp, message

What is the commands that SMTP uses when its sends a single messages to every person vs sending one message to to every user. 
I.E. you send every person in you contact list a message one at a time
vs
sending everyone in your contact list the same message at the same time.
I'm a bit stumped on how SMTP works still

Answer (score 1):

The commands are the same, whether you're sending one message to fifty people at once, or sending a message to fifty people one at a time. The only difference is whether you're talking to your SMTP server once, transmitting one message with fifty recipients, or whether you're talking to your SMTP server fifty times, each time transmitting a message with one recipient. If you're transmitting once message with fifty recipients, you'll be sending the "RCPT TO:" command fifty times during the transmission of the single message, and if you're transmitting fifty messages, then for each of those fifty messages, you'll be saying "RCPT TO:" only once. (You'll also be saying "HELO" (or EHLO) fifty times, and saying "MAIL FROM:" fifty times, and saying "DATA" fifty times, and transmitting the message body fifty times... slightly less efficient, perhaps.)